# XML Parsing with SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to parse the below xml in sql server to get all the 3 Ids

```
<Configuration>
  <ID>1000</ID>
  <ID>1001</ID>
  <ID>1002</ID>
</Configuration>
```

using the query

```
SELECT  CONFIGURATION.value('/', 'varchar(200)') as SID FROM SCHEDULE
```

am getting the results as 100010011002
but i would like to have the results in a column or in a CSV format.

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: What database server are you using?

Comment: Cold you change the schema? as it would be easier if those IDS were in separate rows in a table i.e parse the XML before inserting the data in the table.

Comment: If your data are stored as XML, you should use an XML parser instead of trying to write one by hand.  If you don't need it to be XML, use a simpler format.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using MS SQL Server, this will give you rows.

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml = 
'<Configuration>
  <ID>1000</ID>
  <ID>1001</ID>
  <ID>1002</ID>
</Configuration>'

select
    x.i.value('.', 'int') as ID
from @xml.nodes('/Configuration/ID') as x(i)
```

---

If you only need one value like in this example it is a lot faster (three times) to shred on the `text()` node.

```
select
    x.i.value('.', 'int') as ID
from @xml.nodes('/Configuration/ID/text()') as x(i)
```