# Is there a way to improve performance when sending a large number of IDs to SQL server for filtering?

Tags: c#, sql-server, performance, primary-key, bulk

I use the following C# code to send a list of IDs to SQL Server 2012. It filters the column ID of `mytable` and return the first 50 matching ids.

Actually it take around 180ms to execute the query. The database is local. I am wondering if there is some ways to improve performance. I have noticed performance is directly related to the number of ids send to SQL server rather than the actual number of records in the table. If I send only one thousand records it is very fast (< 1ms). Maybe there is another, more efficient way to send those IDs.

The user defined table `int_list_type` and `mytable` are defined like this :

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
CREATE TYPE int_list_type AS TABLE(Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED)
```

C# code :

```
static void Main()
{       
    List<int> idsToSend = Enumerable.Range(0, 200000).ToList();
    List<int> idsResult = new List<int>();

    Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(@" SELECT TOP 50 t.Id FROM MyTable t
                                                INNER JOIN @ids lt ON t.Id = lt.Id", 
                                               connection);

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ids", SqlDbType.Structured)
        {
            TypeName = "int_list_type",
            Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
            Value = GetSqlDataRecords(idsToSend)
        });

        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            idsResult.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(sw.Elasped);
}

private static IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord> GetSqlDataRecords(IEnumerable<int> values)
{
    SqlMetaData[] metaData = { new SqlMetaData("Id", SqlDbType.Int) };

    foreach (int value in values)
    {
        SqlDataRecord rec = new SqlDataRecord(metaData);
        rec.SetInt32(0, value);
        yield return rec;
    }
}
```

---

EDIT : as suggested by Fabio, I took a look at `GetSqlDataRecords()` method and this is what take most of the time. I tested it separately this way :

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
GetSqlDataRecords(listOfIfs).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: side note: using `TOP x` without an `ORDER BY` caluse means that you get x records, but doesn't mean you get the **first** x records - database tables are unordered by nature, so without an `ORDER BY` clause there is no way to guarantee the order of the rows returned by a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Did you check what is an actual "bottle neck" - database, or your loop in `GetSqlDataRecords`?

Comment: To get a more accurate measure You need to start your stopwatch after the connection.open() statement.  Opening the connection is always slow.  Ideally, you need to cache this or use connection pooling.  Also, stop the stopwatch before you output the elapsed time.  Writing to console is also slow, so need to stop before you do this.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith yes is it improve precision but has said in the OP, those are not the bottlenecks.

Comment: You could try `SELECT TOP 50 t.Id
FROM   MyTable t
       INNER JOIN @ids lt
               ON t.Id = lt.Id 
OPTION (RECOMPILE) ` so that it can take account of the number of rows in the table variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could try passing in the list of IDs as a comma separated list of strings, then within SQL find all where ID IN(ListOfIds).

Have not had a chance to test this but it solved a similar issue for me in the past. Please let me know if it makes any sort of difference (good or bad).

Comment: I have tried this before and this is horribly slow. I ran the query under SSMS profiler and what took most of the time is to parse the query (make sense).

Answer (score 0):

> +1 for using a table value type and passing that in as a parameter. This is a textbook example of how to use table value types.
>   Unfortunately as you have identified, you will still experience performance issues when passing in very large arrays of data.

You could try using XML to pass the values in: [xml parsing with sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669904/xml-parsing-with-sql-query) The XML parser might be more performant in your environment when dealing with larger arrays, a note of warning, keep the namespaces simple or omit them entirely or performance is much worse than the table value type for smaller arrays 100s to 1000s, in larger arrays you may see better performance.

Question, can you re-architect this solution so that the list of IDs is already in the database? Or offload the ingestion of the list of IDs so that this happens first in preparation for your query?

I do this in my applications by allowing the user to manually 'tag' rows, or run scripts or select some pre-compiled logic for selecting the ids.
I store these ids in a Tag table (the user can save the tag list to reuse in other sessions)

Now that the list of IDs is already in the DB, we simply join on the IDs to our selection list. The execution of the query is not any faster than with table value types or any variants of parsing xml, json or string, but we have bypassed the parse step which is generally the most costly. That and that now the data is in the DB it is easier for SQL Server to optimise and cache query execution plans.

> Note: when sending lists of data to be executed in a query either in the form of table value types, table variables or temporary tables, work must be done to hydrate this data list in SQL temp DB.

You might find some fancy solutions that involve configuring the environment to support this scenario, but if you can change the process to ensure the selection list is already in the DB, most of the heavy lifting work is done for you. Then you can use indexing and other traditional DBA maintenance to optimise your query performance even more.